# How to compare two numbers from different pages using Selenium and JAVA (with test fail option., not console message.)

Tags: java, selenium

How to compare values from different pages, using Selenium and Java?Tests must **fail** if values are not similar (No need for console messages).
I have something like:

```
WebElement primaryTotal = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='pull-right]"));
String expectedTotal  = " $3,373.00 ";
String actualTotal = primaryTotal.getText();
Assert.assertTrue(actualTotal.contains(expectedTotal),"Actual total does not contain expected. \nActual;" + actualTotal + "\nExpected:" +expectedTotal);
```

Comment: if the actualTotal is `$3,373.00`, may be you should try this `Assert.assertEquals(expectedTotal, actualTotal);`

Comment: Can you print `actualTotal` and show us the output ?

Comment: This is First element on page#1 :<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm text-right" id="total_billable_amount-253" value="$3,373.00" readonly="" xpath="1">

This is second element on page #2 <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm w-100" value="$3,373.00" readonly="" xpath="1">

I need to compare this two values "value="$3,373.00" and make this pass if equals and fail test if not.

Comment: @IVSOLO your latest comment doesn't seem to match what's in the question. Could you edit the question to reflect the specific problem you need to solve, and what you've tried?

Comment: @Tim Moore This is just more details added in my comment to main question. The question remain the same.

Comment: @IVSOLO the elements in your comment don't match the xpath in the code in the question. We'll need to see that contents that it's checking to see what's wrong. Please also edit the question to clarify what's wrong. Is the test passing when it should fail, or failing when it should pass? I wonder if it's the spaces around the value in `expectedTotal` causing the problem.